# Sql Merge Locking the Entire Target Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, crud

I have used SQL Merge for CRUD operations in a table that holds records more than 3 million and due to merge locks the table this would gives time out errors on other selects and updates in the production environment.

Site has been accessed by multiple users at a given time and same table could be updated by different set of users at the same time.

so based on my scenario is using SQL merge is efficient or do i have to use INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements?

is there are any way that improve merge by only locking the data record instead of locking the entire table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a very stupid default setting in sql server.
For some reason sql server blocks all readers on a table while a writer is using that table. You can correct this oversight from microsoft like this :

```
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON with NO_WAIT
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabase SET MULTI_USER
```

There is an excellent article about this here http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/#comment-2220427

Comment: Thanks @GuidGo for the answer and i have some other clarifications also does this ALTER statements allow concurrent CRUD operations on a table  in sql server.

Comment: What this alter does is allow a select statement to read commited records from a table while an update, delete, insert or merge is busy on that same table. Basicly what transactions are for and how a database should work

Comment: got it @GuidGo but my problem is there might be concurrent updates,inserts on a same table where merge occur since merge locks the entire table end users getting timeouts when they perform CRUD operations

Comment: I am not familiar with merge, but the alter statement above does allows transaction B to perform updates/inserts/deletes on a table that Transaction A is doing updates/inserts.deletes on at that time. The last transaction that calls commit wins.

Comment: The link in my answer explains this very good with an example, you should really take your time to read it